# No parent in style in android-support-v7-appcompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-build, android-sdk-2.3

i imported support-v7-appcompat library, and during build process i got following issue:

```
Error:(380, 5) String types not allowed (at 'blue' with value '').
app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values\values.xml
```

Line (380,5):

```
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult" parent="">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">?android:textColorHint</item>
</style>
```

I am currently using 23.1.1 version of support library. This issue comes up everytime i build the app. I have tried cleaning the code.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId "com.ms.sensors"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 13
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        compileOptions.with {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
            }
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "sensorgraph"
        cppFlags.add("-Werror")
        ldLibs.addAll(["log", "GLESv2", "android"])
        stl = "c++_static"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Check my answer here [other similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40796407/5057093)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
```

with:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: It is present in source code of support library in build folder. I can't change it since it is auto generated everytime.

Comment: Try that change, it seems like the style is having issues finding the correct parent

Comment: Also make sure you have the correct version of the support library and build tools installed in android studio and that gradle is synced

Comment: I have tried this. Still it didn't solved the problem.